# Error while installing Oracle 19c on Redhat 8.1

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I was trying to install Oracle 19c on my Redhat 8.1 server, but i get the following error when i launch the installation

```
[INS-08101] Unexpected error while executing the action at state: 'supportedOSCheck'
```

Is it even supported ? If no, is there any workaround i can do to launch the installation ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a workaround to the Installation of Oracle 19c on Redhat 8.1. Before installing, i set the following environment variable, then i launch the install.

```
export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL7.6
```

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no versions of Oracle certified for RHEL8 or OEL8. 20c will probably be the first one, later this year. As I understand it from posting on other Oracle Communities sites, it is not expected that any of the 12c family (12cR1, 12cR2, 18c, 19c) will ever be certified on RHEL8 or OEL8, but Oracle hasn't really given an official position yet.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4308915?parent=MOSC_EXTERNAL&sourceId=MOSC&id=4308915

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4310638?parent=MOSC_EXTERNAL&sourceId=MOSC&id=4310638

Here's an article that claims to know how to get it to install, but I have not verified it personally. The author notes that the configuration is *not* supported by Oracle and should not be used for anything important - only for testing.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/oracle-db-19c-installation-on-oracle-linux-8

Comment: Thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

Met INS-08101 when I installed Oracle database 19c on Oracle Linux 8 update 2.

1. Temporarily
   At runtime, we can export the variable.

get VERSION_ID

```
$ cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION_ID | awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'
$ export CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL8.2
```

2. Permanently
   Or we can set the variable in the CVU configuration file.

`vi $ORACLE_HOME/cv/admin/cvu_config`

`CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL8.2`